# kubectl get node is returning connection refused

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubeconfig

When I add this command:

```
 sudo kubectl get node --kubeconfig /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf
```

I got

```
NAME     STATUS     ROLES           AGE   VERSION
master   NotReady   control-plane   42m   v1.26.1
```

but when I send:

```
sudo kubectl get node
```

I got

```
E0126 08:58:10.293496   32223 memcache.go:238] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused
E0126 08:58:10.294046   32223 memcache.go:238] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused
E0126 08:58:10.295501   32223 memcache.go:238] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused
E0126 08:58:10.297011   32223 memcache.go:238] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused
E0126 08:58:10.298647   32223 memcache.go:238] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

However, I exported the KUBECONFIG and sending

```
kubectl config view
```

will not return empty.

Shouldn't both work the same?